# How would you access xcargs from Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fastlane

Is there a way to access xcargs passed into fastlane scan from Swift?

Currently, I'm passing in a list of environment variables as arguments through fastlane:

```
scan(
    ...
    xcargs: 'VARIABLE1 ="' + ENV['VAR1'] + '" VARIABLE2 ="' + ENV['VAR2'] + '"'
)
```

I would like to be able to use these values in my Swift code, but I'm having a hard time finding out where I can retrieve them.

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this?